# Header not found despite the use of the -I option

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, include

I have a project with files in different directories. Directory A contains two directories B and C, and C contains a directory D. Files are in B, C and D. I have written makefiles to compile that, with the main makefile in C. 
C Makefile contains the following line :

```
export LDFLAGS = -I ../B -I . -I ../C/D -lm
```

(At first instead of "../C/D" I had written just "./D" but then I changed because of the error I got, just to be sure the path is valid also for B. However it doesn't changed anything)

The makefile in B contains the following rule :

```
%.o : %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $< $(LDFLAGS)
```

When I run "make", there is an error because a file in B has an include of a file in D, and it doesn't find this file. Why ? Thanks for your help !

edit : As I got exactly the same error (same missing file included on the same B header file) when I added the directory with the -I option, and then when I had the LDFLAGS on my B makefile, I didn't notice the file generating this error change : Now it is a .cpp file that include the B header including the D header that provoke the error.
(Don't ask me why there is one cpp file among c files by the way, it's not me that developed that...)
The lines for the cpp file in the B makefile are :

```
%.o : %.cpp
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $< $(LDFLAGS)
```

But the .o of this .cpp file is not on the all rule (it call $(OBJS), define as OBJS = $(SRC:.c=.o)). I guess this is my mistake. Because when I run make, it first go on B directory and compile my c file with the options, and then leave directory, because of the rule :

```
b : 
    @(cd $(BDIR) && $(MAKE))
```

So, when make realise that myccpfile.o is needed, he magically call the line

```
g++    -c -o ../B/myccpfile.o ../B/mycppfile.cpp
```

So now I really don't understand where this call come from, that's really odd because the only rule using g++ have the CFLAGS and LDFLAGS, I don't understand why they disappeared...

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Maybe you could give us a minimal complete example...

Answer (score 0):

Its `CFLAGS` that requires the -I options for the compilation phase of the build. Check the B makefile has CFLAGS set with the appropriate -I options.

`LDFLAGS` will only affect linker options.

Comment: Well as I added $(LDFLAGS) in the rule it should had affected the compilation of the .o, isn't it ? However I tried to add these -I options in the CFLAGS, but I still have the error. Thanks anyway !